# Python Time 'Lag' Effect in URL

Tags: python, url, timestamp, structure

My server's timezone and the data that I have fetched via the following span two consecutive hours. Once the hour changes, the hour that python syntax is getting is not found on the server that is providing the content, since the server jumps to the next hour while the data is not processed yet. In case you are wondering the data in question is weather model data in .grib2 format.

I have the following code now:

```
# /usr/bin/python 
import time 
# Save your URL to a variable: 
url = time.strftime("http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/nonoperational/com/hrrr/para/hrrr.%Y%m%d/hrrr.t%Hz.wrfnatf04.grib2") 
# Save that string to a file: 
with open('hrrr/hrrrf4.txt', 'a') as f: f.write(url+'\n')
```

Is there a way to 'lag' the &H variable in the above URL one hour, or another method that will delay it to ensure a smooth data processing for all desired hours?

Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: I'm not real clear on what your asking, but seems that you should be using datetime objects and then you can add/subtract the timedeltas (hours, min, seconds, etc...) that you want from that object.  https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Comment: could you use UTC time to request info from the server i.e., convert local time on the client to UTC, send it to server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below would print out the datetime of now, and then offset it by subtracting 1 hour, you could also add an hour, or minutes, seconds, etc.... I scrape lots of forums that are in different timezones than my scraping server and that's how I adjust anyway. This also helps if the servers clock is off a little bit too, you could adjust the time back of forward however much you need.

```
import datetime


timenow = datetime.datetime.now()

timeonehourago = timenow - datetime.timedelta(hours=1)

url = timenow.strftime("http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/nonoperational/com/hrrr/para/hrrr.%Y%m%d/hrrr.t%Hz.wrfnatf04.grib2")

offseturl = timeonehourago.strftime("http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/nonoperational/com/hrrr/para/hrrr.%Y%m%d/hrrr.t%Hz.wrfnatf04.grib2")

print url
print offseturl
```

Comment: Thank you, however how would I insert that time into my URL?

Comment: I've edited my answer to add the offset time to the URL like you had. If you're not trying to offset the time to match the timezone of the server, can you clarify exactly your question a bit as to what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Actually, you have answered my question sufficiently - thank you!

Comment: Excellent, can you check the answer as answered please. Thanks and good luck with your project.